# Absorbance by using Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

How should I compute the amount of energy of an EM wave absorbed by a material?
Can I just use the divergence of the Poynting vector?

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: i tried joule heating, electrical conductivity times E square ， but it turns out bad, because it's kinda linearly proportion to electrical conductivity. but when the electrical goes up th like 10^7 , the power absorbed is obviously too high. as is for the poynting vector, the formula is Pabs=-0.5xReal(div(S)) where S is the poynting vector.  but i don't have the imaginary part here. so I used div(S) only. I don't have the results yet ,the codes are still running but i got a bad feeling about it .:) thank you

Comment: Can you outline the setup a bit better? Is this a plane wave travelling in a medium that has a conductivity, or a wave incident upon the surface of such a substance?

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand absorbance, you need to know the theory for absorber. Wheeler and Feynman introduced the absorber theory in 1945. The key point of the absorber theory is the absorber can be called a sink. The sink is a special source. It sends the advance wave out. The advance wave or advance potential is not like the retarded wave. The retarded wave radiate the wave to the future. The advanced wave radiates the wave to the past. The energy of the advanced wave shrinks from infinite distance to the sink. Hence the absorber can absorb much more energy than the Poynting vector offers. 
We know the particle is very small if you calculate the energy received by using Poynting vector times the section area of the particle, the energy can be much smaller than a photon. Hence the absorber is too small to receive a photon. However since the absorber sends an advanced wave to receive the energy it can receive much more energy than Poynting vector offers. Hence, the absorber can absorb the photon. Here the particle perhaps is a dust or an electric charge. People created a concept effect section area of the particle. The effect section area usually is much larger than the real section area of the particle. You should use effect section area times the Poynting vector to calculate the energy received by the absorber.

This actually means the Poynting theorem is the wrong theorem to this problem. The correct theorem is perhaps the mutual energy flow theorem, which consider the interaction between the retarded wave of light source and the advanced wave of the sink.

Radiation and absorption is very complex phenomena. The theory in this is also not unanimous. Poynting vector is not wrong. But when and where you can use it is still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible approach. You can calculate the flux of the Poynting vector over the boundary of the absorbing volume (http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-001-electromagnetic-fields-and-energy-spring-2008/chapter-11/11.pdf , 11.1, eq. (1)). I used this approach to calculate the power absorbed in a thin cylinder heated by a broad electromagnetic beam (http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0405091 , http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0611169 ). The results were later confirmed in experiments (http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1626 , http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0066)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, as the thread in the lumerical knowledge base mentioned. https://kb.lumerical.com/en/layout_analysis_pabs_simple.html There is another method included in that thread. Hope that can help too.

The related material is listed as follows:
The absorption per unit volume can be calculated from the divergence of the Poynting vector,

Pabs=-0.5real(div.vec_P).

It is possible to calculate the absorption directly from this formula (see the Divergence of Poynting vector section), but divergence calculations tend to be very sensitive to numerical problems. Fortunately, there is a more numerically stable form. It can be shown that the above formula is equivalent to

Pabs=-0.5real(iw*vec_E*vec_D) (w is the radian frequency)

With a little more work, we get the desired result

Pabs=-0.5*w*E^2*imag(epsilon)

To calculate the absorption as a function of space and frequency, we only need to know the electric field intensity and the imaginary part of the permittivity. Both quantities are easy to measure in an FDTD simulation.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Exchange! While this link may answer the question, it is discouraged to post link-only answers here (as sites may vanish from the internet or be moved, etc.). Could you maybe provide a sketch of the answers in the linked thread?